# WPF keyDown response time accuracy

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm developing an application in which user can see something and has to react by clicking a key on the keyboard. Reaction time is crucial and the more accurate the better it is.

I wrote sample app inf WPF only a few lines of code to test default settings:

```
namespace Test
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private Stopwatch sw; 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        this.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
    }

    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        sw.Stop();

        lbl.Content = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        sw.Restart();
    }
  }
}
```

`lbl` is a just simple label.

What is strange is that when I press for example space and hold it the value of the `lbl` changes in the range: 30-33.

So I cant predict what is the response accuracy? Is it impossible to have for example 1 ms accuracy? User hits space and at the same time (for example 1 ms accuracy) I can handle it in the event handler?

The main question is:

let's say I have a key-down event handler:

```
Test_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
{
   time = stopwatch.elapsed();
   stopwatch.Restart();
}
```

what is the minimum value of "time" that can possibly occur? Can I be sure that the time value is accurate to 1 ms?
In this method, I start the stopwatch but then I have to wait - how long - for the GUI to refresh?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to measure there, nor how you do it. `KeyDown` is not raised continuously while the key is down (I guess that would be `KeyPress`) so holding the spacebar shouldn't update the label more than once, does it? If you mean that you hold the spacebar before showing the window, then you benchmark the code between the constructor until the window is finally active and pumps events.

Comment: As far as I know dispatching the event is as fast as it can be and works pretty much the same way any other Windows app does: the key being down is handled by the OS, which then dispatches a message to your window message queue, which is then pumped and the corresponding event is raised on the focused control. The accuracy is good enough when compared to human reaction times, _unless you perform work on your UI thread_.

Comment: The speed of a pressed key will depend on windows configuration of key repeat rate. http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-xp/help/adjust-the-character-repeat-rate

Comment: @Tony: wouldn't that be for `KeyPress`?

Comment: Different keyboards/hardware will also have a different delay rate.  For example, cordless keyboards have a higher delay for each keypress than a USB.  Then there are laptop keyboards (integrated), PS/2, bluetooth, adapter delays (e.g. PS/2 to USB), etc.  So, your question is about accuracy, however, I'm not sure a software application can do this "accurately".  In addition to the keypress comment above here are your windows values you are competing with:  http://superuser.com/questions/388160/keyboard-repeat-rate-repeat-delay-values-in-win7

Comment: Additionally, I think that the only way to measure the ultra exact time between the physical Key Press and the processing on the host application is to use some sort of electronics custom hardware tied to the key and to the output on the software.

Comment: Ive updated the question to make the problem more clear

Comment: "Im developing application in which user can see something and has to react by ***clicking*** a key." . Clicking, the mouse? Or pressing a key? And aren't both of those are different to **holding** a key down?

Comment: only key down, the example maybe is not the best but shows that even holding key each time I have different results and I dokt know why, if the wpf response accuracy is 1 ms then each time result should be the same hmm ?

Comment: Is it possible that you create a window object and keep it in memory and dont show it to user and when window is shown we start timer and then on key press we calc time. this way we can avoid window object creation time and.more accuracy can be acheived.

Comment: Strangely enough, the Timestamp property - which should be the time of the event and so what to be used in this case - seems bogus. If the keyboard is left alone for a while, the Timestamp of the first KeyDown event is obviously wrong...

Answer (score 12):

Your test is certainly invalid, it just measures the keyboard repeat rate as pointed out by several other contributors.  But it is useful for its unintended benefit, you can actually see that you won't have a problem with the keyboard.

Most events in Windows occur at a rate that's determined the by the clock interrupt rate.  Which by default ticks 64 times per second, once every 15.625 milliseconds.  That wakes up the kernel and it goes looking to see if something needs to be done, looking for work to pass to a processor core.  Most typically there's nothing to do and the core is shutdown with a HLT instruction.  Until the next interrupt occurs.

So a concern would be that your test could never be more accurate than 15.625 milliseconds.  And your observation matches, by accident, what you see was twice that number.  But that's not actually the case and you can use your program to see that.  Use Control Panel + Keyboard and tweak the Repeat Rate slider.  Note how you can adjust it and get your number to change to values that are not a multiple of 15.625.

This is not entirely an accident, the keyboard controller also generates an interrupt, just like the clock does.  You have positive proof that this interrupt itself is already good enough to get your program to re-activate.  And you can tell that the keyboard controller itself is fast enough scanning the keyboard matrix.  Your error bar from the keyboard won't be larger than +/- 2 msec, about the noise you see in the displayed number.  In case you have a keyboard that scans slower, you can eliminate it with this test.

---

The far bigger concern you have is the video.  The video adapter typically refreshes an LCD monitor at 60 updates per second.  So worst case, the test subject would not be able to physically *see* the image for 17 msec.  And LCD monitors themselves are not that fast either, the cheap ones have a response time of 16 msec or worse.  A side-effect of the Crystal in the Liquid not being able to flip fast enough.

Eliminating the refresh rate error requires that you program synchronizes with the [vertical blanking interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_blanking_interval).  Something you can do with DirectX.  You can find upscale LCD monitors that have response times of about 4 msec, popular with gamers.

Answer (score 5):

First, if [`Stopwatch.IsHighResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx) is `true`, then `Stopwatch` uses `QueryPerformanceCounter`, and it can measure time intervals with <1 ms resolution.

Second, when you press and hold down the space key, Windows starts sending WM_KEYDOWN messages repeatedly, and your stopwatch will measure the interval between these messages. This interval is determined by the registry key [`HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard\KeyboardSpeed`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978659.aspx).

It's default value is 31, which is the fastest repeat rate, which means approximately 30 characters per second. That's why you measured approximately 1000 / 30 = 33 ms intervals.

If you set it to 0, that is, to the slowest repeat rate, which means approximately 2 characters per second, then you should measure approx. 500 ms intervals. I've tested your code with this setting, and I did get 500 ms. (Don't forget to restart Windows after changing KeyboardSpeed!)

You need to catch a single keydown event, not repeated events, so you don't have to change the KeyboardSpeed setting. Your program should just show the object to the user, start the stopwatch, and stop it if a keydown event occurs. `ElapsedMilliseconds` will give the reaction time. Measure it multiple times and use the average.

The problem is, even if `QueryPerformanceCounter` measures elapsed time accurately, there is a delay caused by the keyboard and Windows itself which will increase the measured reaction time. Moreover, the delay is not constant: if Windows is busy at the moment when it should handle the keydown event, then the delay will be larger. So if you take the task seriously, you should calibrate your program.

I mean, you should buy or build a small, microcontroller-based electronic device, which turns on a LED and detects the time elapsed between turning on the LED and the user pressing a button. Do 10-20 (the more the better) reaction time measurements with this device, and with the same test person, do another 10-20 measurements with your program. The difference between the two will give you the delay caused by the keyboard and Windows. This difference can be subtracted from the reaction time measured by your program.

(One could ask, why you shouldn't use the small, but precise electronic device instead of a Windows application. First, manufacturing and selling software is much easier and cheaper than manufacturing and selling hardware. Second, the visual object can be complex (e.g. checkerboard), and complex objects can be rendered much more efficiently on a PC.)

Comment: I might suggest altering the users registry might not be the best way to do this, but simply reading that value and detecting the holding of the specified key.

Comment: @SeToY I altered the registry just to test my hypothesis about the 33 ms interval the OP measured when space was pressed continuously. The precision of time interval measurement is unrelated to this, so the OP should not modify the user's registry.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out another tool to track down your timing here.  Since you're considering the testing of the application's response, and as someone mentioned this involves the OS' messages, you can utilize Spy++ to see the timing of these messages.  I copied the output of pressing space to a window I had been listening for Keyboard messages only, having turned on all output.  I pressed space once and released as quickly as I could on a USB keyboard which is through a docking station.  You can see that it took ~.05ms to process down and up.

```
<00001> 00090902 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_SPACE cRepeat:1 ScanCode:39 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0 [wParam:00000020 lParam:00390001 time:1:07:38.116 point:(183, 290)]
<00002> 00090902 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'32' (32) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:39 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0 [wParam:00000020 lParam:00390001 time:1:07:38.116 point:(183, 290)]
<00003> 00090902 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_SPACE cRepeat:1 ScanCode:39 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1 [wParam:00000020 lParam:C0390001 time:1:07:38.163 point:(183, 290)]
```

Spy++ is a tool provided with Visual Studio.  You can find it at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio XYZ\Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe` where XYZ is 8, 9.0 and 10.0 that I can confirm.

What you could do to further test timings would be to have Spy++ listening for Keyboard commands and WM_PAINT or something, to see how quickly the program responds to a Keyboard message with its UI change.

For instance, the below is the clean log after having Calculator with `3+3` already, then pressing `Enter`.  You see that calculator was able to compute and display before the .062ms it took between KeyDown and KeyUp to process.

```
<00001> 00090902 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_RETURN cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1C fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0 [wParam:0000000D lParam:011C0001 time:1:19:12.539 point:(179, 283)]
<00002> 00090902 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000 [wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000]
<00003> 00090902 R WM_PAINT lResult:00000000
<00004> 00090902 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000 [wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000]
<00005> 00090902 R WM_PAINT lResult:00000000
<00006> 00090902 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000 [wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000]
<00007> 00090902 R WM_PAINT lResult:00000000
<00008> 00090902 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000 [wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000]
<00009> 00090902 R WM_PAINT lResult:00000000
<00010> 00090902 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_RETURN cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1C fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1 [wParam:0000000D lParam:C11C0001 time:1:19:12.601 point:(179, 283)]
```

edit- In Spy++ I suggest going to Logging Options which shows you the Message Options dialog.  Go to the Messages tab, click Clear All, check 'Keyboard' and then scroll through the listbox and select WM_PAINT.  This way you have only the desired messages, otherwise you will be inundated with them.