# High Resolution GetMessageTime()?

Tags: winapi

WINAPI has a function `GetMessageTime()` that returns the time a message was generated in system time, which has a resolution of 10 to 16 ms.  Is there an effective way to get the time an event occurred in interrupt time (100 ns precision), or in some other format with at least 1 ms precision?

Comment: Probably not, but you may be able to get closer than 10-16ms. Can you explain in more detail what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Something resembling midi using a keyboard.

Comment: Just don't use it, details [are here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284345/wpf-keydown-response-time-accuracy/19341974#19341974).

Comment: I didn't test it, but you can try with [`timeBeginPeriod(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757624(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant By that do you mean use QueryPerformanceCounter instead (assuming the loop is dedicated to input via GetMessage and not PeekMessage)?  Do all machines have an interrupt system?

Answer (score 0):

Even with [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the message timing isn't delivered with < 10 ms resolution.  (The timing data comes from the WM_INPUT message.)  As far as I can tell from the keyboard driver sources, the timing data simply isn't collected with < 10 ms resolution.