# Getting higher precision win32 timestamps for rawinput than millisecond

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, raw-input

I am using raw input as my input api for my game and I was looking to get time stamps for the input presses. But everything I find is at millisecond precision (GetMessageTime()). Which is not good enough for my application where every frame is running in 9 ms (VR time budget) and I have to think about speedrunners. meaning that i cannot accurately differentiate different input message in time within a frame if I get multiple input messages within that single frame. This is problematic for all sorts of delta time calculations base on input too, and especially bad in VR where you need accurate time stamps to predict future frame timing. So is there a way to get at least microsecond (nanosecond if possible) precision per input message when it occurred through rawinput. Or do I have to do input through some other win32 api or system.

thanks in advance!

here is how I setup raw input

```cpp
    //do we want the input sink?
    RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[2];
    //Mouse
    Rid[0].usUsagePage = (USHORT) 0x01; 
    Rid[0].usUsage = (USHORT) 0x02; 
    Rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK | RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY;
    Rid[0].hwndTarget = WindowHandle;
    
    //Keyboard
    Rid[1].usUsagePage = (USHORT) 0x01; 
    Rid[1].usUsage = (USHORT) 0x06; 
    Rid[1].dwFlags =  RIDEV_INPUTSINK | RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY | RIDEV_NOLEGACY;   
    Rid[1].hwndTarget = WindowHandle;

    RegisterRawInputDevices( Rid, 2, sizeof( Rid[0] ) );
```

then in my message loop

```cpp
while(bRunning)
{
    MSG Message;
    while( PeekMessage( &Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
    {
        switch( Message.message )
        {
            case WM_INPUT:
            {
                LONG msTime = GetMessageTime();
                //...do stuff with the time stamp and input
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                TranslateMessage( &Message );
                DispatchMessage( &Message );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acquiring high-resolution time stamps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps

Comment: You may be overthinking this. I assume you're running a fixed time loop for movement, physics, and such so you just apply the messages to the next update.

Comment: [High Resolution GetMessageTime()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399511/high-resolution-getmessagetime) may be of interest.

Comment: `GetMessageTime()` is the only API that lets you query the point in time when a given message was generated. It is trivial to increase the precision by multiplying the value, but that doesn't improve the accuracy. `GetMessageTime()` is as accurate as the system allows.

Comment: @IInspectable do you know if it is possible to get a call back function like a hook that can be called directly by the OS when the message is inserted into the queue? that way I could just time it myself?

Comment: @RetiredNinja the problem is that I also have local co-op and time stamps are extra important for determining event ordering at a sub frame level for fairness. so i would rather overthink it now than have angry users later :)

Comment: We all choose our rabbit holes, but you may never finish this game. If you do it might not catch on. If it does nobody may ever have the issue you're currently worried about. If they do the solution may not be anything like what you think it is today. So, good luck.